# Selection of different values in the PHP function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that uses API keys, each API key has its own data and routes. At the moment it works as follows: when the function is called, the first key is triggered, the next request is triggered by the second key. But there was a need to use an additional 2 keys.

How can I make sure that when the function is called for the first time, the first key is used, when the function is called the second time, the second key is used, when the function is called the third time, the third key is used, when the function is called the fourth time, the fourth key is used?

My code:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->setTimelimit($this->timeLimit);
    $count = DB::table('api')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->count();
    if ($count %2 == 0) {
        $this->apiKey = 'first key';
    } else {
        $this->apiKey = 'second key';
    }
}
```

How i can add 2 keys for when the function is called the third time, the third key is used, when the function is called the fourth time, the fourth key is used?

I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: `__construct()` is only called once, when you use the `new` keyword creating the class.  if you want to do something repetitively you need to remove it from the constructor or use some static class variables to maintain state between instantiations

Comment: Why woudl you `order by` when all you want is a count?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it was my mistake, but it works :) i will remove it. and what about my question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the remainder of a modulo 4 in a switch to decide which key to use

```
// using a for loop to simulate your count of rows in a table

$count = DB::table('api')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->count();
$rem = $count % 4;
switch ($rem){
case 1: echo 'use key 1';
    break;
case 2: echo 'use key 2';
    break;
case 3: echo 'use key 3';
    break;
case 0: echo 'use key 4';
    break;
}
```

RESULT

```
use key 4
use key 1
use key 2
use key 3
use key 4
use key 1
use key 2
use key 3
use key 4
```

Comment: I am assuming `$count = DB::table('api')->count();` returns a different number each time, am I correct?

Comment: yes, it can return 10, 11, 12 and different values each  time

Comment: Then in what way does that code not work for you

Comment: You should not be using the FOR Loop of course, that was just to simulate getting different results back from your count

Comment: oh, okay. will think something another :(

Comment: Amended the code to better fit your situation